# why is browser-action always fired? and why is it for the news not fired?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, browser-action

I have two questions, 
first question: why is browser action fired when I open the browser or open a new tab(not only when I click)? 
Another question is: my extestion changes all website colors, but when the website gets more information (such as facebook) after the browser action is fired,  this can not be changed?
what can I do to make the browser action always change all the news too?

my background.js is:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {  
  chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    file:"content.js"
  });
});
```

and my content.js starts with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        hauptProg();
        });
```

Comment: Do you happen to have the script `content.js` also in manifest section `content_scripts`?

Comment: the script content.js ist in manifest section content_scripts.

Comment: So you'll have to choose one ... if you include both, the script will be injected and executed on each page listed in the `matches` section of the manifest and additionally on click of the browser action icon

Comment: thanx, it has worked.
maybe you have an answer for the second question?

Answer (score 1):

The answer on your second (and main) question depends ... on how the destination page has been implemented. There is no general answer, only a few suggestions

- You can work with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to find out when the content of the elements has changed. You could then execute your code again
- Maybe you can see that, let's say, two seconds after page load the additional content has been loaded. Then you could start a timeout with `window.setTimeout(yourMethod, 2000)` to executed your method after 2 secs

Comment: the second suggestino can I not do, 
for example on facebook, the news can after 4 minutes or more
i try the first

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated. The modern way to do this is with DOM MutationObserver. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23623399/getting-dom-object-fails-with-jquery-in-content-script/23625023#23625023) for an example.